# How to show layered Navigation based on Advanced Search Result

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, layered-navigation, advanced-search

I need to show Layered Navigation in advanced Search Result page based on Advanced Search result options.

**For Example:**

If I search `Price 1000-10000`, Then Based On Result Product options only view in layered navigation. Not Full Options.

I added Layered Navigation to advanced result page. Then search by `price 1000-10000` its show some results and Full Layered navigation options.

But, I filter any `city` if any product not there in based on that `city` its show `no product are there`.

I know Functionality works fine. But, I  need to show only available layered navigation options of advanced search result product.

Suggest Me, How can I do that.

Answer (score 0):

you can go for this extension.

Link: https://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/layered-navigation-on-advance-search-result-page.html

Comment: This is extension only available magento 1, I asked for magento 2

Comment: I know some extension out there, but I need to fix via programmatically..